# Audio video sync issue when bluetooth audio device is connected

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, video, alsa

If I play a video on youtube or any other streaming sites after connecting bluetooth headphone to my ubuntu 22, video lags behind the audio. In other words every time video pause for 1 or 2 sec before playing.

This can be solved by changing output configuration from Handsfree Head Unit to High fidelity playback (A2DP Sink). But while changing output configuration to High fidelity playback input Device changes from bluetooth headset to laptop's microphone.

How can I solve audio video sync issue ? Any help is much appreciated.